# Pass a variable to extract from JSON String in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have below JSON String. Now I want to extract each individual field from that JSON string.

So I decided to create a method parse_json which will accept a variable that I want to extract from the JSON String.

Below is my python script -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json

jsonData = '{"pp": [0,3,5,7,9], "sp": [1,2,4,6,8]}'

def parse_json(data):
    jj = json.loads(jsonData)
    return jj['+data+']

print parse_json('pp')
```

Now whenever I an passing `pp` to `parse_json` method to extract its value from the JSON String, I always get the error as -

```
return jj['+data+']
KeyError: '+data+'
```

Any idea how to fix this issue? As I need to pass the variable which I am supposed to extract from the JSON String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just want this:

```
    return jj[data]
```

Your code is trying to look up a key named literally `'+data+'`, when instead what you want to do is look up the key with a name of the function's parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `data` parameter itself.

---

Replace following line:

```
return jj['+data+'] # lookup with `+data+`, not `pp`
```

with:

```
return jj[data]
```